# How does Snowflake work with ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm using SnowFlake to store all data but I want to make text based queries on some tables, so I want to store those tables data in ElasticSearch on which I can easily perform complex text queries . How can I setup ElasticSearch with SnowFlake to sync specific data tables from snowflake.

I've configured a cronjob on AWS lambda function using SageMaker where I'm getting and uploading data on AWS S3 bucket in the form of CSV's files from snowflake. That doesn't seems to be a good fit for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Logstash to pull the data from Snowflake via JDBC driver and then send the data to Elastic Cloud:

Some reference links:

Snowflake JDBC driver
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/jdbc.html

Logstash to Elastic cloud using cloud_id:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/connecting-to-cloud.html

Example Logstash conf file

```
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_driver_library => "/etc/logstash/pipeline/snowflake/dependency/snowflake-jdbc-3.9.2.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver"
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:snowflake://url.eu-west-1.snowflakecomputing.com/?db=dbname&warehouse=House"
        jdbc_user => "user"
        jdbc_password => "password"
        schedule => "15 * * * *"
        statement => "
            SELECT TOP 100000 * FROM dbname.CORE.table WHERE timestamp >= '2038-10-02 00:00:00' AND timestamp < '2038-10-02 23:59:59'
        "
        jdbc_fetch_size => 1000
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        cloud_id => "<cloud id>" 
        api_key => "<api key>"
    }

}
```

To keep both databases on sync you can use the `sql_last_value` parameter, more info:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html#_state